# From the 4 numbers code-point to the unicode character?

Tags: python, unicode

I've got a 4 number string corresponding to the code-point of an unicode character.
I need to dynamically convert it to its unicode character to be stored inside a variable.

For example, my program will spit during its loop a variable `a = '0590'`. (https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0590)

How do I get the variable `b = '\u0590'`?

I've tried string concatenation `'\u' + a` but obviously it's not the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chr` will take a code point as an integer and convert it to the corresponding character. You need to have an integer though, of course.

```
a = '0590'
result = chr(int(a))
print(result)
```

On Python 2, the function is called `unichr`, not `chr`. And if you want to interpret the string as a hex number, you can pass an explicit radix to `int`.

```
a = '0590'
result = unichr(int(a, 16))
print(result)
```

Comment: Hm... the question does not specify Python 2, but it is worth including a variant for that as well.

Comment: That was it! In python3, `b = chr(int(a, 16))` (`chr(int(a))` is not working for `"0590"` or `"05FF"` for example.